# How to debug when a UIViewController not released ever.(Using ARC)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

In my app I found a UIViewCOntroller's dealloc never be called, which cause the memory exhausted and app crashed.

I want know what may caused this issue and how to debug and which tool can be used for this kind of problem.

Comment: are you holding viewController instance in Strong property?

Comment: Simply not deallocating a single view controller won't cause memory exhaustion.  You must have another problem with the structure of your program that causes it to allocate and keep multiple view controllers or use other memory.  You can use the leaks instrument for a start